# How to insert entity with many to many relation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm working with Spring framework. I have two entities, Movie and Actor, so a Movie can have many actors and an Actor can play in many Movie. Following we have the classes:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_actor")
    private List<Movie> movies;

    public Actor(String name, String surname, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public List<Movie> getMovies() {
        return movies;
    }

    public void setMovies(List<Movie> movies) {
        this.movies = movies;
    }   
}
```

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;

@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String year;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies")
    private List<Actor> actors;

    public Movie(String title, String genre, String year, List<Actor> actors) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
        this.actors = actors;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public List<Actor> getActors() {
        return actors;
    }

    public void setActors(List<Actor> actors) {
        this.actors = actors;
    }
}
```

I have used @ManyToMany annotations to define the relation between them.

At this point, I have in H2 a table Actor that has ID, AGE, NAME and SURNAME columns, table Movie that has ID, GENRE, TITLE and YEAR, and a new table MOVIE_ACTOR because of the annotation with ACTORS_ID and MOVIES_ID columns. Until here it seems okey.

Now, if I save a movie (I have implemented the service and repository extending jpaRepository for both entities):

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public void create() {
        Actor actor1 = new Actor("Pedro", "Perez", "40");
        Actor actor2 = new Actor("Alfredo", "Mora", "25");
        Actor actor3 = new Actor("Juan", "Martinez", "20");
        Actor actor4 = new Actor("Mario", "Arenas", "30");

        List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<>();
        actorList.add(actor1);
        actorList.add(actor2);
        actorList.add(actor3);
        actorList.add(actor4);

        Movie movie = new Movie("Titanic", "Drama", "1984", actorList);

        movieService.create(movie);
    }
```

(I know that it is not a get request, but just for check if a movie is correctly saved just accessing to the endpoint) What I obtain is that in the table Movie the 4 columns are added correctly, but neither ACTOR and MOVIE_ACTOR are completed so actorList is ommited, this two tables are empty. Why this happens and how can I solved it?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hi, this is not the best way to create your many to many relationship, please check this post https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ for the best and most efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you implemented something like this in your service methods (you did not show it) but I would assume that it is missing: You do not [cascade](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) anything (respectively save objects of the other class). You should change your `@ManyToMany` annotation to `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})`. This leads to cascading the merge and persist operation (saving a new object or any changes leads to automatically updating the other one).

Also consider adding proper add and remove methods for your lists like described in this [article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) and good [equals and hashCode methods](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/).

In general, you could find very good descriptions of Hibernate related issues on the page of [Vlad Mihalcea](https://vladmihalcea.com/).

## Update: Implementation Based on Post of @Alan Hay

### Model

```
@Entity
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_actor")
    private List<Movie> movies = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addMovie(Movie movie) {
        movies.add(movie);
        movie.getActors().add(this);
    }

    public void removeMovie(Movie movie) {
        movies.remove(movie);
        movie.getActors().remove(this);
    }

    // Constructors, getters and setters...

    // Equals and hashCode methods a la 
    // https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-implement-equals-and-hashcode-using-the-jpa-entity-identifier/
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String year;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Actor> actors;

    public Movie(String title, String genre, String year, List<Actor> actors) {
        this.title = title;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.year = year;
        actors.forEach(a -> a.addMovie(this));
    }

    // Getters and setters...
}
```

### Create Method

```
@GetMapping("/create")
public void create() {
    Actor actor1 = new Actor("Pedro", "Perez", "40");
    Actor actor2 = new Actor("Alfredo", "Mora", "25");
    Actor actor3 = new Actor("Juan", "Martinez", "20");
    Actor actor4 = new Actor("Mario", "Arenas", "30");

    List<Actor> actorList = new ArrayList<>();
    actorList.add(actor1);
    actorList.add(actor2);
    actorList.add(actor3);
    actorList.add(actor4);

    Movie movie = new Movie("Titanic", "Drama", "1984", actorList);

    movieService.create(movie);
}
```

Comment: I have added @ManyToMany(cascade  = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}) and now the actors are added to the table Actor. But there is one problem yet, the relationship table composed by the movie id and actor id is empty, it is not completed. Any idea?

Comment: Yes that was! I forgot to edit the comment, sorry. Now it inserts correctly in all tables Movies, Actors and the relationship table. Now the problem is that if I insert a movie with an actor that is already in other movie in the database, it does not work properly, it should add the new movie, then create the relations in the relationship table, but it should not add the actor again in database. How can it be solved and make a reference to the actor that is already in database?

Comment: You would have to retrieve the Actor entity you want to use from the database. Then, this one should be referenced. Creating a new Actor is not needed anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 issues here.

Firstly, you have not set the cascade options on the relationship.

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
private List<Actor> actors;
```

Secondly, in the case of a bi-directional relationship it is your responsibility to maintain both sides of the relationship in the in-memory model. The relationship here is being managed by Actor (the side without `mappedBy`) but you have not added any movies to the movies collection in Actor.

So, if you iterate actors in your movies constructor and add the movie `a.getMovies().add(this)` then both sides will be set and the data should be saved as requested.

The Hibernate docs suggest `@ManyToMany` mappings should be avoided as in most cases you are likely to want to store additional data related to the association: in your case for example, character name.  A more flexible option is then to create a Join Entity, say, MovieAppearance which has Movie, Actor, and other properties as required.