# How to break circular dependency?

Tags: database, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to model in spring a relation between Movies and Actors. Here we have my two classes:

```
@Entity
public class Movie {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String title;
    private String genre;
    private String year;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "movies", cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    private List<Actor> actors;

//Getters & Setters
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Actor {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    private String age;
    private String dni;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "movie_actor")
    private List<Movie> movies;

// Getters & Setters
}
```

I have the repositories in H2 for entities and the endpoint for the create movies operation of the CRUD prepared. The problem is that when I am going to create the request body with all information of the movie, I find that movies has a list of actors, and the actors has a list of performed movies, that has actors again... and so on. So I don't know how to deal with this infinite dependency when creating a new movie. In the way I have annotated the code, the relathionship table has been created and when inserting a new movie it is supposed that actors are automatically inserted in their table and the relationship table is completed also. In my database I have the following tables: Movie, Actor and Movie_Actor (relathionship table).

Any idea about that? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I would not recommend to insert/ update your movie/actor relationships with the cascading. You should take control of this yourself with another repository that handles associating actors to movies.

Comment: So, should I delete the cascade argument from Movie class and the many to many annotation? And after that, create a new entity called for example movieActor with two ids and a repository that manages the relationship table? In this case, would not I have the same problem? because in movies there is still a field of type actors, and viceversa for actor class with the field of type movie.

Comment: In this moment, in code I am able to save a new movie, and actors and the relationship are automatically updated correctly. The problem is now, that I want to test it with postman, because I need to write the JSON of the body request with the information of the movie but I do not know how to complete it, or even if it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 1):

In the [answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119359/how-to-insert-entity-with-many-to-many-relation/58120054#58120054) I already mentioned some helpful links concerning the @ManyToMany association.

To find out how to interact with a Spring Boot app via Rest API, have a look at the [tutorials of the official website of Pivotal](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/) (creator of Spring). To make it easy, I would start with a simple get request to have a look what is returned. Then, this format of the body could be used to test the other requests.