# Loading nested object of OneToOne relationship

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-rest

I have a class

```
public class ToolSet {

...
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Contractor assignedTo;
...

}

public class Contractor {
...
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "contractors_docs_photos",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "contractor_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "image_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private Set<Image> idPhoto;

...
}
```

now when I query toolset I get the following

```
 "toolset": [
      {
...
        "_embedded": {
          "assignedTo": {
            "firstName": "firstName",
          }
        }
      }
```

how do I load nested objects in Contractor (photos) as well? so that when I load toolset  I see contractor and inside contracor I see its photos

Answer (score 0):

## Proper @ManyToMany Relationship

#### NO FetchType.EAGER

At first, we should have a look at the implementation of your `@ManyToMany` relationship itself. As Vlad Mihalcea explained quite detailed in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/), `FetchType.EAGER` is not a good choice. It results in lots of unnecessary database requests.

#### NO CascadeType.REMOVE

Furthermore, cascading all changes could result in serious issues. Removing a specific object could be cascaded automatically to removing lots of other objects. As [described in this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) (scroll down a little bit), `CascadeType.REMOVE` should be avoided for `@ManyToMany` relationships. `CascadeType.ALL` includes `REMOVE`. Instead, you should use `@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})`

Another example of a `@ManyToMany` relationship could be found in [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58119359/how-to-insert-entity-with-many-to-many-relation/58120054#58120054).

## Initialise Lazy Relationships

Lazy relationships (like the 'good' `@ManyToMany` mentioned) are not initialised by Hibernate (the ORM used by Spring Data automatically). Only a proxy with the relevant primary key could be found in the respective variable. The complete object gets loaded automatically from the database when someone tries to access the variable. This results in an additional database request.

If you already know beforehand that the object would be needed (the variable accessed), you should initialise the relationship when requesting the parent from the database (when you request a `ToolSet` from the database, its `idPhoto` should be loaded as well.

In SQL, this means a join between those different tables. In JPA, a join does not automatically mean that the data is loaded. Therefore, you should use a fetch join or a entity graph to initiliase the lazy annotations. [This article](https://thoughts-on-java.org/5-ways-to-initialize-lazy-relations-and-when-to-use-them/) gives a good overview how to use these different ways of initialising.

#### Example with Criteria API

In JPA there are different ways of implementing database requests: JPQL as a query language and the Criteria API (easier to refactor, less error prone). As I am a fan of the Criteria API, I will show you an example how the relationships could be initialised with it and the usage of an entity graph.

```
public Optional<ToolSet> findById(long id) {

    EntityGraph<ToolSet> graph = entityManager.createEntityGraph(ToolSet.class);
    graph.addAttributeNodes("assignedTo");

    Subgraph<Contractor> subgraph = graph.addSubgraph("assignedTo");
    subgraph.addAttributeNodes("idPhoto");

    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<ToolSet> cq = cb.createQuery(ToolSet.class);
    Root<ToolSet> root = cq.from(ToolSet.class);

    cq.where(cb.equal(root.get("id"), id));    // Assumption of id as PK
    TypedQuery<ToolSet> typedQuery = entityManager.createQuery(cq);
    typedQuery.setHint("javax.persistence.fetchgraph", graph);

    ToolSet response = null;
    try {
        response = typedQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
    catch(NoResultException nre) {}
    return Optional.ofNullable(response);
}
```

In this example, I assume that your primary key for `ToolSet` is called `id`. To see mistakes even better at compile time, have a look at hibernate-jpamodelgen. Then, you could write things like `cq.where(cb.equal(root.get(ToolSet_.ID), id))`.

Above, I use `Optional`. It does not have to be used. Anyway, you could reasearch the advantages of using it.